# Proof verification.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Let $x,y$ be real numbers, with $x < y$. Show that if $x$ and $y$ are rational, then there exists an irrational number $u$ such that $x < u < y$.

Now, since $y - x > 0 \implies \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}} > 0$

if we take $u =  x + \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}$, we are done.

My question is, is this ok? I feel like i need to prove that $x < x + \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}} < y$, if that is the case, subtracting $x$ will give the desired result? i.e $0 <\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}} < y - x$.

A follow up question would be, how would i begin to show that there exists a rational between the reals?

This is my attempt, but it's a proof by contradiction;

suppose that there is no rational number $q$ between $x$ and $y$, with $x < y$.

take the set of real, irrational numbers $\frac{a}{b} + \sqrt{2}$, where $b$ is fixed and $a \in R$

suppose that $x = \frac{a}{b} + \sqrt{2}$ and $y =\frac{a + c}{b} + \sqrt{2}$ for some real $c>0$ then

$y - x = c/b$, but if i divide this by 2 and add this to $x$, i get an irrational number.

EDIT. 
I am aware that there are proofs, such as;

We must choose an $N > 1/(y-x) \implies 1/N < (y-x)$, then theres exists an integer multiple of $1/N$ such that $x < r < y$, where $r = M/N$. However,  I would like to know whether my approach holds any water.